# about basic file organization

Tags: ocaml

in file testmodule.ml

```
module TestModule =
struct
  type my_type = MyType1 | MyType2
end
```

How can I use TestModule in top-level?

after "ocamlc -c testmodule.ml" (this generated testmodule.cmo/cmi)

I tried "open TestModule", but error "unbound module TestModule" occured.

```
        Objective Caml version 3.10.0

# open TestModule;;
Unbound module TestModule
```

then, I tried making top-level with that module. but...

```
indi@www:~/std/toq$ ocamlmktop -o mytop testmodule.ml
indi@www:~/std/toq$ ./mytop
        Objective Caml version 3.10.0

# TestModule.MyType1;;
Unbound constructor TestModule.MyType1
# open TestModule;;
Unbound module TestModule
```

What can I do for using my TestModule???

Answer (score 4):

The directives you can use in the toplevel to that effect are listed [in the manual](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/manual023.html#toc90).

You can try  `#use "testmodule.ml";;`, or, alternatively `#load "testmodule.cmo";;` after having compiled your module.

Answer (score 2):

As huitseeker mentioned, you can use `#use "testmodule.ml";;`.  However, this will make the module `Testmodule` avialable, and your `TestModule` module is actually `Testmodule.TestModule`.  `.cmo` files (generated from `.ml` files) define a module whose name is that of the CMO with the first letter capitalized.  Therefore, I would omit the `module TestModule ...` part of your code, and simply put your code in a file called `testModule.ml`.  You can then compile it and use `#use "testModule.ml";;` to access the module.

Answer (score 0):

Tu summarize: a few minor details all conspired together against you :-)

First, as mentioned previously, you need to load the code into the toplevel with either `#use "testmodule.ml";;` for source files or `#load "testmodule.cmo";;` for compiled files, or to use `ocamlmktop`. This explains why your first attempt did not work: you did not load the code.

Second, you defined `module TestModule` in a file called `testmodule.ml`. Keep in mind that the file defines its own module based on its name. So, in order to access your module, you need to write `Testmodule.TestModule`. This explains why your second attempt did not work: the code was loaded but had an unexpected name.

You might wish to remove the `TestModule` definition and rename the file to `testModule.ml` (or the perhaps more idiomatic `test_module.ml`).